# Как разбить один коммит на 10 не потеряв код?

Tags: git

Я случайно закоммитил 10 файлов одни коммитом. А хотел 10-ю разными коммитами - по одному коммиту на файл. Можно как то достать файлы из коммита и заново закоммитить уже по одному? Но при этомм код нужно сохранить, потому что сами изменения то хорошие. Коммит плохой получился. Я пользуюсь программой SmartGit, но могу и через cmd.

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD~` - откат к коммиту, предшествующему текущему, при этом все изменения останутся на месте http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/git-undo-commit/

Comment: @Etki, Вау! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 6):

> В любой непонятной ситуации делай новую ветку.

Сначала обеспечить "путь отхода" на случай, если всё пойдёт не так:

```
git branch backup
```

Если дела пойдут плохо, в ветке `backup` изменения точно останутся. Потом эту ветку можно удалить.

Теперь отодвигаем нужную ветку на коммит назад, оставив изменения на месте:

```
git reset --mixed "HEAD^"
```

Почему `mixed`?

- `hard` сбрасывает всё
- `soft` оставляет индекс и файлы (всё будет выглядеть, как будто был `git add`)
- `mixed` сбросит индекс (якобы `git add` не было), но не тронет файлы

Comment: Спасибо, уже успел сделать как посоветовал @Etki) Все получилось. Но теперь буду и git branch backup делать на всякий случай. А если просто создавать новую ветку и потом откатывать коммит, то кода не останется ни в новой ни в старой? То есть backup - это особая такая ветка?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Нет, имя с потолка. Назвать можно и иначе.

Comment: ааа, понял) значит я и вашему совету тоже последовал) То есть делать новую ветку. Если что то пошло не так в ней останется код, если все хорошо - просто удалить ее.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Всё так. Любые сомнительные действия лучше сопровождать резервной веткой. А если забыли, может спасти `git reflog`.

Comment: А ещё лучше, любые сомнительные вещи делать на локальном клоне подопытного репо.

Comment: @zed в этом почти никогда нет надобности. Разве что это какое-то совсем суровое вмешательство вроде удаления из `.git` "чего-то ненужного" руками, в обход команд гита.